# Format changing in adding dates function javascript

Tags: javascript, html, date

I am using a Javascript function, which lets to add days to the current date, but I am facing problem when i tried to change the Date format, here is my working code,

```
  <body onload="addDate();">
         <br/>
        <h1>Adding number of days to current date in Javascript</h1>
        Today's Date (MM / DD / YYYY) : <input type="text" id="date1" readonly/> <br/> <br/>
        Number of days to add : <input type="text" id="days" onChange="datechange()" /> <br/> <br/>
        New Date (MM / DD / YYYY) : <input type="text" id="date2" readonly/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
              function datechange()
              {
                    var d = document.getElementById('days').value;
                    var myDate = new Date(document.getElementById('date1').value);
                    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + parseInt(d));
                    document.getElementById('date2').value = (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (myDate.getDate()) + '/' + (myDate.getFullYear());
              }
              function addDate()
              {
                     date = new Date();
                     var month = date.getMonth()+1;
                     var day = date.getDate();
                     var year = date.getFullYear();
                     if (document.getElementById('date1').value == '')
                     {
                           document.getElementById('date1').value = month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
                     }
              }
        </script>
```

I tried to change the date format to DD/MM/YYYY,with this code,

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
              function datechange()
              {
                    var d = document.getElementById('days').value;
                    var myDate = new Date(document.getElementById('date1').value);
                    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + parseInt(d));
                    document.getElementById('date2').value = myDate.getDate() + '/' + (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (myDate.getFullYear());
              }
              function addDate()
              {
                     date = new Date();
                     var month = date.getMonth()+1;
                     var day = date.getDate();
                     var year = date.getFullYear();
                     if (document.getElementById('date1').value == '')
                     {
                           document.getElementById('date1').value = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
                     }
              }
        </script>
```

But I am getting the wrong value. Please someone, where I went wrong.

Comment: Can you please create a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Can't make a `new Date()` with `dd/mm/yyyy`. Try this:

```
function datechange() {
    var d      = document.getElementById('days').value;
    var from   = document.getElementById('date1').value.split('/');
    var myDate = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]);
    myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + parseInt(d));
    document.getElementById('date2').value = myDate.getDate() + '/' + (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/j5sqg/

Comment: No, I have changed that too, but still I am getting the problem.

Comment: What is the problem? You said you're getting the wrong value - what value are you getting and what value are you expecting then?

Comment: if, I add "2" days to the current date it is showing 5/5/2015.

Comment: Ah I see it's because above that line you're creating a new Date object which can't parse dd/mm/yyyy. See my edit for a workaround.

Comment: Awesome It works :) Can u explain, why can't we create new date() with dd/mm/yyyy ?? and also tell me  var from   = document.getElementById('date1').value.split('/');
    var myDate = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0]); these lines doing ?

Comment: There's just not a parser for that string format baked into the constructor. Your code example in your comment is making an array from the date string by splitting it into chunks separated by '/'. Then it creates a new Date() object and passes in the 3rd item, the 2nd item (minus one so we know that's the month because months in JS have a 0 based index, 0-11 where 0=Jan and 11=Dec), and then the 1st item.